# Best way to insure my college daughter's laptop?

Tags: laptop, security

My daughter is about to head off to college in the fall. I love her dearly, but I have low confidence that she won't misplace her laptop in the first week!

Does anyone know any good options for insuring her laptop?

Other issues like data protection and recovery will be separate questions I think - but suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Could use a bluetooth dongle and a (hopefully) bluetooth enabled mobile to make it beep **really loudly** if she gets out of range.

Comment: Nice :-) Maybe some kind of electric shock collar... what, too cruel!? :)

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but 'get a cheaper laptop' might be good advice if she does lose it. Netbooks do great for most tasks.

Comment: @GorillaSandwich:  the problem is that they don't want to lose it, and be able to track it down again if possible...thus, they will still lose money, data, etc when they lose a netbook, however cheap it is...

Comment: as i understand it, this question is asking for advice about insurance.  insurance questions are not about computer hardware or software (even if you're asking about insuring a computer).  @Ross, if you edit this question to turn it into a hardware/software question, it may be reopened.  flag for moderator attention if you need us to look at it again.

Comment: Fair point. But I'm torn between something cheap and something that will last for all four years. For example, one of the unibody macbook pros looks like it would last her well. But that's going to attract attention as well as being an expensive loss.

Comment: I swithered on posting it because I thought it might be off-topic. But I thought I'd throw it out and check. I figured fellow geeks might have a similar problem. No worries closing it. Thanks.

Comment: I've used http://www.absolute.com/products/lojackforlaptops before.  The company works w/ the local police to track and recover stolen laptops.  If she leaves it somewhere and later on finds it is now gone, that is arguably theft and thus covered under that provision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have homeowner's insurance, it may be covered. It depends on the riders and deductible, so you'll have to check your policy or contact your insurance agent.

Some manufacturers sell extended warranties that may include protection against theft and/or accidental damage. Again, it depends on the specific details of the policy.